# how to use the intent function for tabactivity from list activity?

Tags: android

*In my application i am using listview activiy from that using an intent function it has to goes to tabactivity.
ReleaselistActivity.java

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor Release = mDbHelper.fetchRelease(id);        
    String Releasename = Release.getString(Release.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE));
    Release.close();
    Intent i1= new Intent(this, TabLayout.class);
    i1.putExtra(ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID_REL, id); 
    i1.putExtra("project", gprojectName); 
    i1.putExtra("release", Releasename); 
    startActivity(i1);


}
```

i cant go to the tabactivity,if i click in the listview,it shows my application has stopped.

Comment: at com.Ibetter.tdm.ReleaseListActivity.onListItemClick(ReleaseListActivity.java:177),if i click this line in log cat,its showing in startactivity(i1);

Comment: I mean you show full error stacktrace

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class
 android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)

Comment: com.Ibetter.tdm.ReleaseListActivity.onListItemClick(ReleaseListActivity.java:177)
android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: If i click the listview,it has to go to the tabactivity functionaility,that how i am done this one,but right now it shows that my application has stopped?

Comment: show your AndroidManifest.xml, it seems you not registered your activity properly

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: android:name="com.Ibetter.tdm.ProjectListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Ibetter.tdm.ProjectEditActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_project_edit" >
        </activity>

Comment: android:name="com.Ibetter.tdm.TestEditActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test_edit" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Ibetter.tdm.TestListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test_list" >
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.Ibetter.tdm.ReqListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_req_list" >
        </activity>
         <activity        android:name="com.Ibetter.tdm.ReqEditActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_req_edit" >

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov.tell me i am using startActivity(i1),this alone gives problem to go to the tabactivity?while clicking my listview its shows that my application has stopped?

Comment: try to update your question and put androidManifest there, now it is difficult to understand xml code. The problem is that you trying to start activity with class name TabLayout, but i can't see this activity in yor manifest, application just can't find this activity and crashes. Take a look how to start activities http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#StartActivity

Comment: @GeoryGobozov. thanks dude,now i think i made mistake on the androidmanifest.xml

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.Ibetter.tdm.TabLayoutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tab_edit" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.Ibetter.tdm.ProjectListActivity">
        </activity>--you told like that,i added  but its also not working

Comment: Maruthi042, Just post your androidManifest here http://pastebin.com/ and give me a link

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dKQUqB56  this link having my androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: @GeorgyGobozov. you can see my androidmanifest.xml in the above link i given.confirm that it is correct or not?

Comment: My problem not yet solved,can anyone help to solve my problem.